# Are fixtures supported in Djongo?

Tags: django, djongo

I'd like to create fixtures and use them in tests. But when I try to load them e.g. by running `./manage.py loaddata test.json`, I get `DeserializationError`. Traceback:

```
django.core.serializers.base.DeserializationError: Problem installing fixture 

'/app/test.json': Value: OrderedDict() stored in DB must be of type dict/listDid you miss 

any Migrations?: (template.template:pk=5) field_value was 'OrderedDict()'
```

This is just one example, but, basically, it complains about any JSON string it encounters. So it looks as though test.json is deserialized once and values for JSONFields are left as JSON strings. So it throws an error here:

```
    # from Djongo's JSONField class 
    def to_python(self, value):
        if not isinstance(value, (dict, list)):
            raise ValueError(
                f'Value: {value} stored in DB must be of type dict/list'
                'Did you miss any Migrations?'
            )
        return value
```

There is a kinda similar [issue on Github](https://github.com/nesdis/djongo/issues/285) that is abandoned. So I am not sure if fixtures are even supposed to work with Djongo at this point.

Thanks in advance for any clarifications.

Comment: Fixtures do work in Django, but they have to be properly formatted. Are you sure your json matches the model you have? It's hard to see the problem without the json and model files

Comment: @Danielle the question is about Djongo, which is a package that enables Django to work with MongoDB. And it seems it doesn't work with fixtures, since I believe it's correct for Django's JSONField to have a value of JSON string type while Djongo expects either list or dict :(